# Protractor: Unable to create a new browser instance in a test

Tags: angular, browser, protractor

I am trying to video call and I need two browsers to imitate two different users. Therefore I am trying to create a new browser instance in between my test. I am using the following code to create a new browser instance:

```
const config = {
       browserName: 'chrome',
       platformName: 'windows 10',
       'acceptInsecureCerts': true,
       'chromeOptions': {
             'args': [ "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream", "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream", "--ignore-certificate-errors"]
       },
};
const driver: WebDriver = new protractor.Builder().withCapabilities(config).build();
newBrowser = new protractor.ProtractorBrowser(driver);
await newBrowser.driver.get('https://google.com');
```

When I run the code I get the following error at the last line

```
- Failed: Cannot read property 'onPageLoad' of undefined
```

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I am using protractor 7.0.0

Comment: I want to see a resolution if it is possible, please ping me when someone replies :)

Comment: I realized that I need to use usingServer() to connect to the selenium hub that is spun up locally before tests start. At the moment looks like i am using a default chromedriver and i am creating a session that is not part of the selenium server. And therefore,  I am  seeing this issue

Comment: awesome, so you're saying that apart from chromedriver issue, you are able to control multiple browsers in protractor?

Comment: yes I am able to control chrome and firefox. I have drivers for both of them locally

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I found the bottom solution to work in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking though this library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-parallel-instances) and source code for protractor I am now finally able to create any browser instance provided I have the webdriver and the necessary device connected or in reachable condition. I have used the following functions to create a browser instance

```
    const config = {
           browserName: 'chrome',
           platformName: 'windows 10',
           'acceptInsecureCerts': true,
           'chromeOptions': {
             'args': [ "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream", "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream", "--ignore-certificate-errors"]
           },
    };    
    async createNewBrowserSession(capabilities: any): Promise<ProtractorBrowser>{
        const conf = new ConfigParser();
        const config = conf.getConfig();
        config.capabilities = capabilities;
        const ptorRunner = new ProtractorRunner.Runner(config);
        const newBrowser = await ptorRunner.createBrowser(config.plugins_);
        return newBrowser as ProtractorBrowser;
    }
    newBrowser = await this.createNewBrowserSession(capabilities);
    await newBrowser.get('https://google.com');
```

This generates a browser instance using the webdriver available to the machine running protractor. If you want to use the selenium server started by protractor you need to make a few more changes

In your protractor.conf.js, set

```
    directConnect: false
```

and update the above code to the following:

```
    const config = {
           browserName: 'chrome',
           platformName: 'windows 10',
           'acceptInsecureCerts': true,
           'chromeOptions': {
             'args': [ "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream", "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream", "--ignore-certificate-errors"]
           },
    };    
    async createNewBrowserSession(capabilities: any): Promise<ProtractorBrowser>{
        const conf = new ConfigParser();
        const config = conf.getConfig();
        config.capabilities = capabilities;
        const ptorRunner = new ProtractorRunner.Runner(config);
        const newBrowser = await ptorRunner.createBrowser(config.plugins_);
        return newBrowser as ProtractorBrowser;
    }
    await browser.getProcessedConfig().then((obj) => {
        capabilities.seleniumAddress = obj.seleniumAddress;
    });
    newBrowser = await this.createNewBrowserSession(capabilities);
    await newBrowser.get('https://google.com');
```